# Revert 1.9.3 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: ce-1.9.3.0

Is there any way to revert/rollback to 1.9.2.4?

I upgraded my dev site to 1.9.3 but it broke my image uploader and I did not notice until some days after. By then I had already done a lot of stuff because this was supposed to be a new site. It would take many days/weeks to start over from scratch. So I hope there is a way? Could I revert the files or would there still be some irreversible stuff in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [diff](https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/14a15cd52baede0e5d600e8c653f33e9) between those two versions, there are four database changes to be undone besides the core files reversal. However, it seems much easier and less error prone to simply make the uploader work – if this is the only issue/reason. There are as many possible reasons the uploader fails as there are solutions out here. It's probably not even 1.9.3 crashing your image uploader but SUPEE-8788 (contained within 1.9.3) which you should install anyway so your problem will likely persist even after going back to 1.9.2.4 and applying SUPEE-8788.

Comment: Hi @pong, thanks for the reply. I think so too, but I have used several days to get it to work with no luck. I have made several posts and no one seems to be able to fix this bug